# EditText on ListView not working properly with addTextChangedListener

Tags: java, android, listview

I have populated weight conversion functionality on listview using string array. I want to change the values of each entity when new value is typed by the user on any entity i.e KG, Pound and Gram. But addTextChangedListener is not responding properly and values are getting wrong on each EditText.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        convAdapter adapter = new convAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.unitc_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

convAdapter.java

```
public class convAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    static TextWatcher watcher=null;
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.########");
    private String unitWeight[] = {"Pound","Kilogram","Gram"};
    private static String unitWeightValue[] = {"2.204","1","1000"};
    private String unitWeightValueUpdated[] = unitWeightValue;
    private static Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public convAdapter(Activity a) {
        activity = a;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    public int getCount() {

        return unitWeight.length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unit_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtItem.setText(unitWeight[position]);
        viewHolder.etValue.setText(format.format(((double) Math.round(10000*Double.parseDouble(unitWeightValueUpdated[position]))/10000.0)));
        viewHolder.txtItem.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.etValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(unitWeight[position].equals("Kilogram")){
                    int i = 0;
                    for(String pos: unitWeightValue ){
                        unitWeightValueUpdated[i] = format.format(((double) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(pos)*Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(viewHolder.etValue.getText())))));
                        i++;
                    }
                }else{
                    int i = 0;
                    for(String pos: unitWeightValue ) {
                        unitWeightValueUpdated[i] = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.etValue.getText().toString())* Double.parseDouble(pos) /
                        Double.parseDouble(unitWeightValueUpdated[i]));
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtItem;
        EditText etValue;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            txtItem = view.findViewById(R.id.tvUnitName);
            etValue = view.findViewById(R.id.etValue);




        }
    }


}
```

unit_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:weightSum=".2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUnitName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Unit"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="100"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/unitc_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Problems:

1. addTextChangedListener are being called multiple times unnecessarily
2. Values are not updating properly.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does `BaseAdapter` extends from `Adapter`?

Comment: BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter, SpinnerAdapter i.e BaseAdapter is imported as import android.widget.BaseAdapter;